# How to get values inside multiple divs through same class name in JQuery?

Tags: javascript

How to get 3.1 and 3.2 from following HTML using JQuery?

```
<div class="question3"> 
<div class="pure-u-1-2 questionNumber">
  <p class="boldText">3.1 </p>
</div>
<div class="pure-u-1-2 questionNumber">
  <p class="boldText">3.2 </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Tried JQuery:

```
  $.map($('.questionNumber'), function (el) { alert(el.html) });
```

How to get question numbers dynamically for class question3 in JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var arr = $('.questionNumber').map(function(){ return +$(this).text() }).get()
```

This will produce this array: `[3.1, 3.2]`

Note that your own code fails because you use `html` instead of `html()`.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. But What if i want array for only <div class="question3"> ?

Comment: @fatherazrael then use `$('.question3 .questionNumber').map(function(){ return +$(this).text()} ).get()`